# Chain morphism into a subcomplex homotopic to identity

Tags: homological-algebra

Let us assume we have a chain complex $(X_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$ of vector spaces and a subcomplex $(Y_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$.

Let us furthermore assume that there exists a morphism 
$f_\bullet : (X_\bullet,\partial_\bullet) \rightarrow (Y_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$
and a homotopy operator
$\Psi_k : X_k \rightarrow X_{k-1}$ 
such that $\Psi$ gives a homotopy between $f$ and the identity. We have

$x - f_{k} x = \Psi_{k+1} \partial_{k} x + \partial_{k-1} \Psi_{k} x$

for $x \in X_k$.

Then $f_\bullet$ induces isomorphisms on homology. I have read the claim that if $f_\bullet$ takes image in the subcomplex $(Y_\bullet,\partial_\bullet)$, then it induces a isomorphism on homology between the subcomplexes.

But I do not see that - I believe you need additional assumptions, such that 
$\Psi_k ( Y_k ) \subseteq Y_{k-1}$. Can you prove the claim without such an additional assumption.

Comment: With the current definition of $f_\bullet$, it always takes image in the subcomplex you mention. Moreover, where do your $A_i$'s live? Could it be that there should be two subcomplexes involved in this question or am I just missing something?

Comment: @HSN Thank you for pointing out this typo. There is only one subcomplex involved.